# vb.net delegate and invoke - Multithread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates, thread-safety, invoke

I am trying to understand how delegates and invoke work.

So I build a form, with a label and a button.

When someone clicks on the Button, the Text changes to "Stop" and a counter starts counting up. This counter should be displayed on a Label. This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

  Private t1 As Thread
  Private sek_ As Integer = 0

  Private Sub btn_read_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_read.Click


    If btn_read.Text = "Read" Then

        btn_read.Text = "Stop"
        t1 = New Thread(AddressOf stopw_)
        t1.Start()

    Else
        lbl_stopw_.Text = ""
        btn_read.Text = "Read"

    End If

  End Sub

  Private Delegate Sub stopw_D()

  Private Sub stopw_()

    Do While btn_read.Text = "Stop"
        sek_ = sek_ + 1

        If lbl_stopw_.InvokeRequired Then
            lbl_stopw_.Invoke(New stopw_D(AddressOf stopw_))
        Else
            lbl_stopw_.Text = sek_
        End If

        Thread.Sleep(1000)

    Loop

    sek_ = 0

    If t1.IsAlive Then t1.Abort()

  End Sub

End Class
```

If I start debugging, the form still freezes and the label does not get updated. If I delete all the delegate and invoke stuff and use `Me.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` Its working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That Invoke() call is quite wrong.  Triggers a *firehose* bug, the UI thread can't do anything but service those invokes.  Wait a bit longer and you'll get to see this site's name.  Use BackgroundWorker to fall in the pit of success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to execute a method on the same thread that the control was created on. Since code can only be executed one line at a time in each thread, executing a method on the control's thread will result in the method being "queued" until the other code in that thread, prior to the method, has completed. This makes it thread-safe as there will be no concurrency issues.

A [**`Delegate`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) is simply a class holding the pointer to a method. It exists so that you can use methods as if they were ordinary objects (in this case you pass it to a function). The [**`AddressOf`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) operator is a quick way of creating a delegate.

Now, you have a few issues in your code. First of all, you should not try to access or modify ***ANY*** UI element from a background thread. Whenever you want modify or check a control you must ***always*** invoke.

More specifically, I'm talking about your `While`-loop:

```
'You can't check the button here without invoking.
Do While btn_read.Text = "Stop"
```

It is better if you create a `Boolean` variable that indicates when the thread should run.

```
Private t1 As Thread
Private sek_ As Integer = 0
Private ThreadActive As Boolean = False
```

Set `ThreadActive` to `True` before you start the thead, then in your thread's `While`-loop check:

```
Do While ThreadActive
```

---

Now, there is another issue. Your UI freezes because of this:

```
If lbl_stopw_.InvokeRequired Then
    lbl_stopw_.Invoke(New stopw_D(AddressOf stopw_))
```

***NEVER*** invoke the ***the same*** method which the thread runs on! Doing so starts the processing all over again, **but on the UI thread**. Your loop makes the UI thread completely busy, which is why it doesn't redraw itself.

So when you are to update something, always invoke a seperate method. If you target **.NET 4.0 or higher** you can use [**lambda expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) for a quick, inline delegate:

```
If lbl_stopw_.InvokeRequired Then
    lbl_stopw_.Invoke( _
        Sub()
            lbl_stopw_.Text = sek_
        End Sub)
Else
    lbl_stopw_.Text = sek_
End If
```

However if you are targeting **.NET 3.5 or lower** you have to stick to the normal way of using delegates:

```
'Outside your thread.
Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDelegate(ByVal Text As String)

Private Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal Text As String)
    lbl_stopw_.Text = Text
End Sub

'In your thread.
If lbl_stopw_.InvokeRequired Then
    lbl_stopw_.Invoke(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), sek_)
Else
    UpdateLabel(sek_)
End If
```

Alternatively, in order to minimize the amount of code you have to write you can create an [**extension method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) to do the invoking for you:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub InvokeIfRequired(ByVal Control As Control, ByVal Method As [Delegate], ByVal ParamArray Parameters As Object())
        If Parameters Is Nothing OrElse _
            Parameters.Length = 0 Then Parameters = Nothing 'If Parameters is null or has a length of zero then no parameters should be passed.
        If Control.InvokeRequired = True Then
            Control.Invoke(Method, Parameters)
        Else
            Method.DynamicInvoke(Parameters)
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Usage, **.NET 4.0 or higher**:

```
lbl_stopw_.InvokeIfRequired( _
    Sub()
        lbl_stopw_.Text = sek_
    End Sub)
```

Usage, **.NET 3.5 or lower**:

```
lbl_stopw_.InvokeIfRequired(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), sek_)
```

When using this extension method you don't need to write `InvokeRequired` checks everywhere:

```
Do While btn_read.Text = "Stop"
    sek_ = sek_ + 1

    lbl_stopw_.InvokeIfRequired(New UpdateLabelDelegate(AddressOf UpdateLabel), sek_)

    Thread.Sleep(1000)
Loop
```

---

And finally, this is just unnecessary:

```
If t1.IsAlive Then t1.Abort()
```

The thread will always be alive when it reaches that `If`-statement since it hasn't exited the `stopw_` method yet. But once the thread has exited the method it will end normally, so there's no reason to call `Abort()`.

The answer got a bit long, but I hope it to be helpful!

Comment: Wow, awesome! I think i got it now! Many many thanks for your effort

Comment: @azmd108 : No problem, I'm glad I could help! Good luck with your project!